# Making a lite Version in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am trying to make a lite version to my iPhone App. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2098) to the dot and copied the target. Everything there went great but when I enter `-DLITE_VERSION`into the `LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language` setting in the build tab, the define does not work correctly. When I enter `#ifdef LITE_VERSION`, I build without errors but yet the button that I am trying to set as hidden is still showing. Any idea's. BTW I change the active scheme by selecting it from the bar right next to the run button on the top left of xcode 4.

Here is my code:

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION

    [play setHidden:YES];

#else
    [play setHidden:NO];
#endif
```

Comment: when you set your “play” button to hidden without preprocessor directives, is it really hidden ? if no, maybe your code is setting the hidden property to YES somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is defined a `#define` in the `-Prefix.pch` of my lite version like so:

```
#define POSTPASSFREE 2
```

In my 'pro' version I have this `#define`:

```
#define POSTPASS 1
```

I then used conditional compilation, similar to what you have above in those areas where things need to be slightly different:

```
#if POSTPASSFREE
    return NO;
#else
    return YES;
#endif
```

Using both:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#if POSTPASS
    return 2;
#elif POSTPASSFREE
    return 1;
#endif
}
```

Switching between schemes will activate the various sections at build time.

Comment: But my main app is the only one with a prefix.pch. My lite version does not have it. All I did was duplicate the main game target and changed the name and bundle id in the plist. How should I make/find my lite versions prefix.pch?

Comment: @MacN00b - Looks the tutorial created the new target in a completely different way than I did.  I used the Xcode 4 menu (File--> New--> New Target) to create my new target, which created a new Info.Plist, main, and pch file for my target.

Comment: you can set the prefix header file for a target in the build settings - ie make a copy for the lite version (which you edit). search for "Prefix Header" under build settings for the new target, and you will see a line something like "myApp/myApp-Prefix.pch" - change it to the name of the (new) pch file ( eg myApp/myApp-Lite-Prefix.pch